# How do I call a function automatically in the API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**Hello everyone**

I wrote an API using Asp.Net Core .I want a function to run automatically every 10 minutes.
How can I do such a thing?

I need your help . Thanks in advance.

```
public void AutoUpdate()
{
   var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
   var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
   var dbData = _provinceDataDal.GetAll();

   var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
   {
     UpdateData(dbData);
   }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
}
```

I used a method like use but it didn't work as I wanted. Because it works only once.

I want it to run my updateData function above for 10 minutes without having to trigger it when the API first runs and again.

Comment: A bit of elaboration? What function, how is it related to API, and why didnt simple timer work out?

Comment: @AgentFire 
I updated my question

Comment: The are lots resources on the web how to run a cron job or scheduling a task in ASP.NET Core, just google it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since asp.net core 2.1 are the background tasks with hosted services.

First, configure the services in Startup

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   //Other DI registrations;

   // Register Hosted Services
   services.AddHostedService<MyServices>();
}
```

After, you implement the ExecuteAsync method with the code of what you want to do

```
    public class MyServices : BackgroundService
    {
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("Starting");

            stoppingToken.Register(() =>
                _logger.LogDebug("Stopping."));

            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogDebug($"Working");

                // Your code here

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), stoppingToken);
            }

            _logger.LogDebug($"Stopping.");
        }
   }
```

More documentation in [this link's Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: You guys are great. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `IHostedService`. Example with timer you can find here - [Timed background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks). Keep in mind that it is good to use a `BackgroundService` base class during implementation.